# mysql_connect not working after EasyApache update

Tags: php, mysql, linux, whm, mysql-connect

I am running out of ideas here and hoping someone can help me out.

I am using WHM, and used the EasyApache to enable zip.  Upon completion all my mysql_connect statements stopped working.

So running a basic piece of code like:

```php
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'usrhere', 'passhere');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Returns: "Could not connect: Access denied for user 'cpaneluser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".  So you'll notice the username and password here are being ignored.  Am I missing an extension or library or something?

The strange thing is I am also running Zend Framework2, and this has no problem connecting to the DB with the default code.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You're not missing anything, you just have not granted the proper access to that user.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard. I will definitely make the switch, but this is a little more urgent then that.  Also, in regards to proper access.  I can easily login and do everything in phpmyadmin with the same credentials.  If you look at what I describe under the code, it is just ignoring the username and password I provide and trying to connect with the cpanel account name and no password.

Comment: Code generally does not "ignore" anything. There has to be some other factor at play.

Comment: I agree. That's exactly why I think I'm missing some sort of extension or core php code is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to anyone else, for some reason when doing EasyApache it put me in sql safe mode.  Changing that to off in my php.ini resolved everything.